# UITableview on nib (view) doesn't reload (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview, nib

I wanna reload some data in my **FAQViewcontroller**. The tableview is placed in a **nib file (view)** which is loaded with the Viewcontroller, called this way:

```
FAQViewController *vc = [[FAQViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FAQViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In viewDidLoad of FAQViewcontroller, the tableview is displaying the right way (I see the separator lines and when I'm changing the backgroundColor, it is working well). But there's no information to display yet, so the cells are empty (as expected).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;

[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FAQCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FAQCell"];

if (self.faqData == nil || [_faqData count] == 0) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        [[DataModel sharedInstance] getFrequentlyAskedQuestions:^(NSError *error) {

        }];
    });
}
}
```

When the network call is done, this function in the FAQViewcontroller is called:

```
- (void)setFaqData:(NSArray *)faqData {

_faqData = faqData;
NSLog(@"%@", _faqData);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^() {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
}
```

But reloadData is doing nothing. The numberofrowsinsection isn't called.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return _faqData.count;
}
```

I don't know what to do about it. Never had this before (normally I code in Swift, maybe I forget something in Objective-C)?

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you set the table view datasource properly ?

Comment: Be sure that you connected your table view in Interface Builder and as Ratul Sharker pointed out, the data source delegate methods are all implemented correctly.

Comment: Is `self.tableView` non-`nil`?

Comment: It is not nil in viewdidload, but nil in the function SetFaqData

Comment: Tableview, datasource, and delegate are connected in file's owner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try making tableView as a strong reference?
something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView
```

Comment: I tried above, but nothing changed. But when I connected the datasource and delegate for the third time, and cleaned, suddenly it worked. I don't know what the problem was exactly, but thanks all for your help!!